# Background image translate?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm attempting to get basic side scroller movement down in canvas, and I'm in a good spot with the movement itself, but I can't seem to get the background to translate. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how translate works? The main canvas is translating fine (the one the 'player' is on) but the bg canvas won't budge.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5SG8/1/

Fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5SG8/1/embedded/result/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
(function() {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    bg = document.getElementById('canvas2'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    bgctx = bg.getContext('2d'),
    width = 1280,
    height = 720,
    player = {
        x: width/2,
        y: height/2 - 15,
        width: 16,
        height: 24,
        speed: 3,
        velx: 0,
        vely: 0,
        jumping: false
    },

    keys = [],
    friction = 0.9,
    gravity = 0.3;

canvas.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {keys[e.keyCode] = true;})
canvas.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {keys[e.keyCode] = false;})

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
bg.width = width;
bg.height = height;

var bgimg = new Image();
    bgimg.src = 'bg.png';

bgimg.onload = function bgload() {bgctx.drawImage(bgimg,0,0);}

function playerupdate() {

    if (keys[68]) {
        if (player.velx < player.speed) {player.velx++;}
    }
    if (keys[65]) {
        if (player.velx > -player.speed) {player.velx--;}
    }

    player.velx *= friction;

    player.x += player.velx;
    ctx.translate(-player.velx,0);
    bgctx.translate(player.velx,0);


    ctx.clearRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000'
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);


    requestAnimationFrame(playerupdate);

    console.log(player.x)

}

window.onload = playerupdate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, the `translate` function translates the context of the canvas, but it does not redraw, so you'd need to:

```
// note you probably want the ctx to translate in the opposite direction of 
// the player's velocity if you want the appearance of movement (if that's 
// what you want)
bgctx.translate(-player.velx, 0);
bgctx.clearRect(0, 0, bg.width, bg.height);
bgctx.drawImage(bgimg, 0, 0);
```

Knowing that, you can probably figure it out from there.  If your background is non-repeating (and you prevent the player from moving off the edges), then this might be the solution.

If your background is repeatable, you'll need to do a bit more work, as translating the image will quickly move it off screen.  You can solve this by drawing a repeating fill created from the image rather than drawing in the image itself, something like:

```
// on image load, replacing your initial `drawImage`
bgimg.onload = function bgload() {
    var ptrn = bgctx.createPattern(bgimg, 'repeat');
    bgctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
    bgctx.fillRect(0, 0, bg.width, bg.height);                               
}

// then in the loop
bgctx.translate(-player.velx, 0);
// Here you'd fill a square *around* the player, instead of just
// repainting the image.
bgctx.fillRect(player.x - width/2, 0, bg.width, bg.height);
```

Comment: Thanks much for the response. I don't know how I forgot about the need to redraw.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to let you know that courtesy of your help, I was able to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5SG8/3/embedded/result/

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As @numbers1311407 says in his answer you will need to redraw the image.

But translate is strictly not necessary here - just redraw the image into a new position instead.

```
bgctx.drawImage(bgimg, -player.velx, 0);
```

**[Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Y5SG8/2/)**

You don't even need to use clear as the image will overdraw anything - the only thing you need to take care of is wrapping/tiling when the image is out of "bound" or you will get tearing (that applies to both approaches).

Comment: Hey, just wanted to let you know that courtesy of your help, I was able to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5SG8/3/embedded/result/

Thanks!